# How do I get Sitecore's home url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

How do I just get http://www.mysite.com/en the main part of the Site homepage url without the item path? Ultimately, I want to append the Model.Url to

This:

```
Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions urlOptions = new Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions();
urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
url = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item, urlOptions);
```

Gives me "http://www.mysite.com/en/undergraduate/business/new-information-landing-pages/Akron-stories"

```
Model.Url
```

Gives me "/undergraduate/business/new-information-landing-pages/Akron-stories"

```
var context = new SitecoreContext();
url = context.GetHomeItem<Base_Page>().URL;
```

Gives me "/"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the parameter in web.config on the linkprovider

```
<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="Always" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
```

or set it on your UrlOption

```
Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions urlOptions = UrlOptions.DefaultOptions;
urlOptions.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Always;

// Fetch the start item from Site definition
var startItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.ContentStartPath);

var url = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(startItem, urlOptions);
```

Also always use `UrlOptions.DefaultOptions` to copy the current settings from the linkmanager options

Comment: Error 22 The best overloaded method match for 'Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item, Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions)' has some invalid arguments. It doesn't seem to like Sitecore.Context.Site.ContentStartItem

Comment: Sorry - did'n test the code, the Site.ContentStartItem was not an item, i have edited the code